# Batch file leap year?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How should I create a batch file program that if I input a year the program will identify if it is a leap year or not.

```
@echo off
cls
echo.  LEAP YEAR
echo. Enter Year:
exit /b 0
```

Well, its just that i need help like suggestions to what should i do.

Comment: How a human would decide it?

Comment: depends to what he/she wants to input. like if he/she input 2016 then it is a leap year..

Comment: Aha, could it be that there is a rule about leap years? Or is it random? Do you know if 2028 will be a leap year?

Comment: after 4 years. it will be a leap year..

Comment: In my version of wikipedia there are the rules described. Assuming that you are only interessted for the next 80 years, then only one rule remains

Answer (score 7):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "year=Enter year: "
set /A "leap=!(year%%4) + (!!(year%%100)-!!(year%%400))"
if %leap% equ 1 echo Is leap year
```

Accordingly to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) a year is leap if it is divisible by 4 excepting if it is also divisible by 100, in which case it is leap only if it is also divisible by 400 ("divisible" means that the remainder of the division by the given number is zero). This way, 2000 and 2400 are leap years because their remainders when they are divided by 400 are zero, but 2100, 2200 and 2300 are not: these are special cases because their remainders when they are divided by 100 are zero.

In `set /A` command the `!` boolean NOT operator gives 1 if its operand is zero and gives 0 in any other case, so `set /A "leap=!(year%%4)"` gives 1 if the year is divisible by 4 and zero in any other case; this gives the first part of the result.

After that we need to subtract 1 from this value in years 2100, 2200 and 2300, but subtract nothing in years 2000 and 2400; that is:

```
year    year%%100    a=!!(year%%100)    year%%400    b=!!(year%%400)    a-b
2000    0              0                0              0                 0
2100    0              0                100            1                 -1
2200    0              0                200            1                 -1
2300    0              0                300            1                 -1
2400    0              0                0              0                 0
```

If the year is *not* divisible by 100 then both `a` and `b` values are equal to 1, so `a-b` is zero and the result is given just by the original remainder by 4.

This way, the formula `set /A "leap=!(year%%4) + (!!(year%%100)-!!(year%%400))"` gives the complete result.

Comment: @jeb: Done! I don't like when the explanations are larger and more difficult to write than the solution itself **`:/`**

Comment: nice. May be this will work even faster `set /A "leap=!(year&3) + (!!(year%100)-!!(year&15))"` (bitwise instead of checking the modulo)

Comment: @npocmaka: I like it! However, I challenge you to write an _understandable_ explanation of such method for people with no experience, like the OP...

Answer (score 2):

It does not check if the input is correct:

```
@echo off
set /p year=enter a year:

call :isLeap %year%

exit /b 0
:isLeap
setlocal

set "year=%~1"
set /a _4=year%%4
set /a _100=year%%100
set /a _400=year%%400

::set _

if not %_4% equ 0 (
  echo not leap
  exit /b 0
)

if %_100% equ 0 (

        if not %_400% equ 0 (
           echo not leap
           exit /b 0
        )
)

echo leap
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse PowerShell's date constructor.  If it errors attempting to set the date object to February 29 of *nnnn*, then it's not a leap year.

```perl
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Usage: %~nx0 year
    goto :EOF
)

>NUL 2>NUL powershell "get-date -date '%~1.2.29'" && (
    echo Leap year!
) || (
    echo Not leap year.
)

goto :EOF
```

You can do the same with a JScript hybrid.  It's a little more code, but it's much faster.

```perl
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Usage: %~nx0 year
    goto :EOF
)

cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%~1" && (
    echo Leap year!
) || (
    echo Not leap year.
)

goto :EOF
@end
WSH.Quit(new Date(WSH.Arguments(0), 1, 29).getDate() - 29);
```