# Missing operator in an expression

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to define if my year is a leap year. I took the code from @Aacini: [Batch file leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157817/batch-file-leap-year)

```
set /A "leap=!(year%%4) + (!!(year%%100)-!!(year%%400))"
if %leap% equ 1 echo Is leap year
```

but when i run it it says that there is a missing operator.
Do you have any idea about how I can fix it?

Comment: You're setting year somewhere, right?

Comment: Do you have [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled? well, don't as it consumes the `!` operators, or escape them in case like `^!`...

Comment: @SomethingDark yes i'm setting it in the beginning of my code  and it's displaying the right date when i use `echo %year%`

Comment: @aschipfl no I'm not.

Comment: You are executing the code in a batch file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be easier than it is made out to be. Parentheses can be used in the `SET /A` statement, but modulus will happen before addition or subtraction anyway.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A YEAR=%1
SET /A "LEAP=YEAR %% 4 + YEAR %% 100 - YEAR %% 400"
IF %LEAP% EQU 0 (ECHO %YEAR% is a leap year)
```

Use this by making the year in question a parameter to the command script.

```
CALL leapyear.bat 2017
```

HT to @aschipft about `YEAR` not requiring percent characters in `SET /A`.

Comment: Yes, it's working thanks. But as I test 2016, leap is equal to 0; So as far as I understand the code, it means that it's not a leap year while we get leap=1 for 2017 which means that's a leap year. The reality is that 2016 is a leap year and 2017 is not. Should I change the code to `IF %LEAP% EQU 0 (ECHO Is leap year)` ?

Comment: I believe this code returns zero for leap years and a non-zero value else; anyway, it is not necessary to put `%` around `YEAR` as `set /A` resolves variables even without...

Comment: I have corrected the EQU test in the last statement.